# How to crop Fisherface Image Dataset

Tags: opencv

I just have this link for my gender recognition using opencv and fisherface. I followed the link below

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html

What I don't understand is on how to crop the images from the steps provided. Is there a standard size of image that I will use for this?

Comment: in the tutorial you linked, they are _using Google Images with the faces filter turned on_, and then _manual_ selection of proper results. You can however apply face detection on your images so you can do this automatically.

Comment: Is there a size that I should follow to crop the faces properly?

Comment: no, but you can detect the face and then resize to a given reference size. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31405755/5008845) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a information on how to crop faces properly. cropface() method in python code crops face by getting eye coordinates and scales the crops size according to distance between center points of left and right eyes. See the code at this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html#aligning-face-images):